# Typescript: Enum Key in Mapped Types

Tags: typescript, generics, enums, definition

I have an enum for http methods:

```
export enum HttpMethod {
  GET = 'GET', POST = 'POST', /*...*/
}
```

Then I define a basic method type, that can have any `HttpMethod` as key:

```
type Methods = {
  [M in HttpMethod]?: any;
};
```

A basic Route type could use this Method type:

```
type Route<M extends Methods = any> = {
  methods: M;
}
```

So I can define any route like:

```
interface AnyRoute extends Route<{
  [HttpMethod.GET]: AnyRequestHandler;
}> {}
```

So far so good. Now I want to add a `Validator`:

```
type Validator<R extends Route, M extends HttpMethod> = {/*...*/}
```

And only want to allow adding `Method`s to the `Validator`, that are defined in the `Route`:

```
type RouteMethodValidators<R extends Route> = {
  [M in keyof R['methods']]?: Validator<R, M>;
};
```

Although my IDE seems to understand it, I get the following errors:

- `Type 'M' does not satisfy the constrain 'HttpMethod'.`
- `Type 'keyof R["methods"]' is not assignable to type 'HttpMethod'.`

Is there any way I can tell typescript, that this is is definitely a member of `HttpMethod`?

Answer (score 4):

Your problem mostly lies here: `type Route<M extends Methods = any>`

First of all, a default value `any` will result in `M` being of type `string` in `RouteMethodValidator` because `Route<any>['methods']` is `any` and `keyof any` is `string`.

Now, changing the default value to `Methods` still won't solve the problem because you do `M extends Methods` which basically means that `M` can have more keys than the ones defined in `Methods`, i.e. more than are defined in `HttpMethods`. But in `Validator` you only allow values of `HttpMethods`.

I believe your best option would be to make `Route` not generic.

```
type Route = {
  methods: Methods;
}

type RouteMethodValidators<R extends Route> = {
  [M in HttpMethod]?: Validator<R, M>;
}
```

Comment: thanks for your thoughts, but with changing the keys to `[M in HttpMethod]`, I can add any HttpMethod to the Validator, not only the ones defined in the Route.

Comment: @SaschaGalley Ok, I see now what you were trying to do. Can you give a full example what you'd like to do and also what `type Validator` is supposed to do?